# eventlistener doesnt update global variable

Tags: javascript, global-variables, addeventlistener, event-listener

I'm trying to make an ascii to char and char to ascii translator
I want to update the shift and the str in the eventlisteners, but they dont update them globally only in their scopem I cant add the new values into the arguments

```
const outerWheel = document.querySelector('.outer-wheel');
const innerWheel = document.querySelector('.inner-wheel');
const centerWheel = document.querySelector('.wheel-center');
let key = document.querySelector('.key');

key.addEventListener('input', function(e){
  let key = e.target.value
  outerWheel.style.transform = `translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg)`
  innerWheel.style.transform =  `translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(${key * 14.4}deg)`
  centerWheel.style.transform = `translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg) rotate(${key * -14.4}deg)`
})


let shift = 0
let str = ''
let strBox = document.querySelector('.encrypt-text')
let shiftBox = document.querySelector('.encrypt-key')
shiftBox.addEventListener('input', function (e)  {
   shift = e.target.value // this is supposed for shifting the ascii codes
})
console.log(shift)
strBox.addEventListener('input', function(e){
  let str = e.target.value // i want this value to calculate the end of the for loop 
console.log(str)

 
  let codedStr = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  let char = str.charAt(i)
  let ascii = char.charCodeAt(0)

  let shiftedAscii = ascii + shift
  switch(true) {
    case (ascii >= 65 && ascii <= 90):
      if (shiftedAscii < 65) {shiftedAscii += 26} 
      if (shiftedAscii > 90) {shiftedAscii -= 26} 
      break;
    case (ascii >= 97 && ascii <= 122):
      if (shiftedAscii < 97) {shiftedAscii += 26} 
      if (shiftedAscii > 122) {shiftedAscii -= 26} 
      break;
    default:
      console.log('nem betu')
      break;  
  } 
  let codedChar = String.fromCharCode(shiftedAscii)
  codedStr += codedChar;
}
codedStr= codedStr.substr(codedStr.length - str.length)
const encryptedText = document.querySelector('.encrypted-text')
encryptedText.innerHTML = codedStr
```

Comment: Everything is working correctly here, `shift` and `str` are properly being updated. You can check by logging `console.log(str, shift)` in `strBox`. Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9gmkLo5r/). I don't get what your problem is.

Comment: Where are you trying to return values from the event handlers? There's no receiver for those values, they're directly going to the bitspace. Notice, that the console.logs outside of the event handlers are executed for a long time before the events are fired, that's why you're getting empty/zero logs.

Comment: I think I get it, but I don't how how I'm supposed to put the new values into the arguments

Comment: i just copy the full code so you will see the whole thing

Comment: I'm sorry for being a newbie, I'm just struggling with this the past few hours

Comment: `let str = e.target.value` this creates a new variable named `str` in the scope of the event handler, shadowing the globally defined variable. If you don't want to create a new variable, don't use `let` there, just assign, i.e., `str = e.target.value;`

Comment: thanks for the help, i finally got it and i will upload it to my git repository